# Shiny CSS dependency

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, shiny

I'm using shiny.fluent package, I want to use other dashboard's or packages features in shiny.fluent but the features styles change. For example, I want to use DT with bootstrap theme or bs4dash card in shiny.fluent.

I guess there is conflict between shiny.fluent CSS and bootstrap CSS.

Is there any way to use different features with their own CSS in same app?

[image: example]

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.fluent)
library(DT)
library(palmerpenguins)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluentPage(
    DTOutput('dt')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$dt <- renderDataTable(
      datatable(palmerpenguins::penguins, style='bootstrap')
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion. 
Not tested. Do not load via `library()` or `require()` but use them as you have used `palmerpenguins::penguins`.

Comment: Did it work? What's the current situation?